# Watir from Ruby on Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir, watir-webdriver

I have the requirement to run a Watir test code from the Ruby on Rails framework. My ruby on rails hello world works perfectly and so does my Watir test (when i run from the irb and when run as an individial ruby script ) , but my requirement is to call the watir code from within the rails controller, which is giving a cannot Load Watir error.

This requirement is very urgent, and i can't figure out what the error is.

Note: The rails application is run on the netbeans 6.9 IDE and uses the native ruby interpreter in the system (not the default jruby)

I have the following versions:
ruby : 1.9.3
watir : 3.0.0
Rails : 3.2.8

```
LoadError (cannot load such file -- Watir):
  app/controllers/watir_controller.rb:4:in `<class:WatirController>'
  app/controllers/watir_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

This is my controller class which calls the watir script:

```
class WatirController < ApplicationController

## the Watir controller
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
# set a variable
test_site = "http://www.google.com"
# open the IE browser
ie = Watir::IE.new
# print some comments
puts "Beginning of test: Google search."
puts " Step 1: go to the test site: " + test_site
ie.goto test_site
puts " Step 2: enter 'pickaxe' in the search text field."
ie.text_field(:name, "q").set "pickaxe" # "q" is the name of the search field
#puts " Step 3: click the 'Google Search' button."
ie.button(:name, "btnG").click # "btnG" is the name of the Search button
puts " Expected Result:"
puts "  A Google page with results should be shown. 'Programming Ruby' should be high on the list."
puts " Actual Result:"
if ie.text.include? "Programming Ruby"
  puts "  Test Passed. Found the test string: 'Programming Ruby'. Actual Results match Expected Results."
else
  puts "  Test Failed! Could not find: 'Programming Ruby'."
end
puts "End of test: Google search."
end
```

Comment: And the code that causes the error is...?

Comment: Also, are you using RVM? Is Watir in your gem list? Is there some kind of env.rb for rails (I am not that familiar with Rails)?

Comment: i'm not using RVM, it is a ruby on rails app. Yes Watir is on the gem list.

Comment: found the solution..had to include the 'watir' gem in the Gemfile , this seems to be the requirement of rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand as to why you need to use Watir inside of your Rails controller?

Watir is for browser automation to test things out which means that you should put it into your test/spec directory and put watir to the Gemfile into development and test group like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "watir"
end
```

Since you're using Rails and you probably would test the application written in Rails then i'd also recommend to use [watir-rails](https://github.com/watir/watir-rails). Also, if you're using [RSpec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec), use [watir-rspec](https://github.com/watir/watir-rspec). This means that your Gemfile should look like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "watir-rails"
  gem "watir-rspec"
end
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Whether you would use Watir on a controller is not the question.

Comment: Sometimes to answer question correctly you need to ask more questions to find out the motivation behind the original question. Here, it seems that OP wants to solve some kind of a problem, but seems to be wanting to do it in a totally inefficient and wrong way that's why I would not be too keen to answer to the original question, but find out the correct question and answer it then. Based on that, downvoting my answer is not grounded, don't you agree?

Answer (score -1):

You have to include it in your gem file.

Gemfile

```
gem 'watir'
```

controller

```
class MyApp::WebCrawlerController
    require "watir"
    require "nokogiri"

    def index
      browser = Watir::Browser.new
      browser.goto 'http://www.google.com'
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
    end
end
```

Comment: It does answer the question, but I don't think that this should be the correct answer because the question itself is not clear enough and seems to be heading in a wrong direction. If the idea is to crawl some page in a controller action then Watir is a totally wrong choice of a tool - lower level http libraries should be used for that.

Comment: @JarmoPertman Perhaps lower level HTTP libraries can't be used. It's possible that it's a page where data is loaded via JS, and therefore Watir is needed to properly load the data. I don't think it's usually the place of a SO answer to decide whether or not the poster is asking the right question or not. If OP wanted a better solution to their problem, they would have asked for it, but they specifically asked how to use Watir, so that's the answer we should provide, no?

Comment: Yeah, it is all possible, but since OP-s question was vague without an explanation of why watir (or other browser automation tool) is to be used from Rails action then I wouldn't make an assumption that this is the best solution to the problem. It is not uncommon that people don't know what to exactly ask to solve their problem and that's why extra questions are necessary. I think that SO is so (pun intended) about asking the right questions because if wrong questions are asked with wrong answers then the quality as a whole drops.